# Designing a simple web search engine: how to address the need to search for exact phrases?

Tags: search, search-engine

I'm strongly considering a web search engine for my next pet project. All the basic principles are clear, but some details are not. Namely, I can't find a neat way to search by exact match, e. g. "The Who".

This requirement imposes limitations on how I can modify the source text:

1. I can't use a list of stop words (high frequency, low relevance words like prepositions - they might be very relevant in some corner cases!).
2. I can't use stemming (converting words to their basic lexical form). If I do use it, I can't tell "program" from "programmed" and so on.

Not being able to cast all words to their basic forms and to throw away common low value words means a much, MUCH larger index. And worse, for the common search queries that do benefit from stemming, how do I even implement it? The only solution I see is keeping two indices - one with actual words and one with stemmed words, but having to keep two copies of the Internet is not really a solution - one is already plenty to make me scratch my head.

Comment: Two copies of the "Internet".   Google Bing and few other are a bit ahead of you.  Maybe scale back a bit.

Comment: @Paparazzi: your point eludes me.

Comment: Do you have the horsepower to crawl the Internet for the words let a alone build a search engine?

Comment: @Paparazzi: yes. Almost anyone does these days, with efficient enough programming. And don't forget cloud computing is pretty cheap these days, too.

Comment: Really, Google goes to WA for cheap power and 1 acre facility and anyone these day has the power.

Comment: @Paparazzi: diminishing returns. Every 1% percent improvement (in web coverage, crawler complexity, ranking complexity etc.) requires exponentially more resources. I don't aim to overthrow Google, clearly.

Comment: Your words - "having to keep two copies of the Internet".

Answer (score 2):

A search engine would normally use an inverted index in order to be able to efficiently search through large amounts of data (the same principle is used if the documents come from a source different than a web crawler). You split the text into words, and for each word the inverted index contains IDs of the documents which contain that word. In order to search for a phrase, such as "internet search", you need to find documents which contain both words, and contain them exactly in the order given. This means you need an additional structure to hold the positions of words in each document.

Now, if you want an "exact match", things become much more complicated. There are countless possibilities for even two words, they could be separated by some special sequence such as "internet??#++-search" and you can't have all possible values as keys in your inverted index.

So, if you want to be able to match any substring, you are pretty much bound to using linear search instead of an index, which is prohibitively slow. As you will easily check, even google doesn't support search for arbitrary character sequences and will strip most non-alphanumeric characters.

So, implementing phrase search is quite possible, but exact match search for any arbitrary character search is not feasible for huge amounts of data such as internet search.

Comment: I didn't mean searching for arbitrary character sequences, just specific forms of **words** rather than their basic forms.

Comment: In this case you can add a document to the list both for the stemmed form and the actually used form of the word and OR the lists together. It does make your index larger but that's how most search engines do it. If you have a position index for phrase search, both forms of the word are marked at the same position.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Comment: @MichałKosmulski: it does make the index larger because now you have to specify words twice, along with their occurrences (in the stemmed form and the actual form).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That's exactly what I wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

Stem, but sort by relationship. So exact matches come first, then close lexical pairs (programmed vs. programming, programmer), then stems, then entirely different forms (programmatic, programmatical...). English suffixes are fairly consistent, so while you'll need to store your data across two related tables (for the sake of the answer I'll assume your search terms are stored in a database) one of them is much shorter than the other; table [x] contains all the stems you can think of (or generate, you'd be insane to do it manually), while table [y] contains every relevant suffix. Given words are broken into two indices, one stem-index and one suffix-index, and that pair is used in the search process itself.

The related words ("lexical pairs") can be generated by repeating the search process with increasingly different suffixes: first you'd search with suffixes that are only one or two characters off from the input, then three or four, and so on. If you're handling arbitrary-length words, then you might store a standard length property for each class of suffixes and vary the repeated searches by proportional difference instead of absolute character length.

You could build a lexical parser that sorts words into adjectives, nouns, or verbs to possibly make the stem-suffix match more efficient, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Not going to search the Internet with a dictionary.  Too many words in the Internet for in memory collection.

Comment: Yeah, not completely sure why I wrote that. Corrected to "database" :)

Comment: Still not a good word.  It would be two tables in a database.

Comment: Ugh, I'm half asleep. Sorry >.<

Comment: On that, wouldn't it technically use three or more tables? One table for the stems, one table for the suffixes, one relational table to combine them into something that the application can easily access?

Comment: I gotta say I don't exactly understand the idea. I mean, if "winning" is a different word from "won", then clearly I need to keep both in the index and store occurrences of each separately. That, and joining huge tables is to be avoided whenever possible, I strongly suspect it will make queries that much slower.

Comment: Yeah, the system breaks down with irregular forms such as "winning" vs. "won"; they're the exception though, so I'm not sure they'd be a huge problem. The advantage is that alternative forms are only crawled if the input stems into a basic form in the first place.

I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect it would be possible to create the system I'm describing without tons of joins all over the place. It's a simple series of one-to-many connections, not a full language processor.

Comment: Elaborating on the advantage I described before, most languages tend to re-use grammatical suffixes because a fairly regular language is easier to use than an irregular one and language use tends towards the path of least resistance. So a small set of suffixes can have a large positive effect on your search time: If you have ten particular stems and each stem has ten possible suffixes you'll end up storing 100 terms overall, whereas ten listed stems connected to ten possible suffixes amounts to just 20 words in your system.

Comment: Additionally, you don't actually HAVE to use tables and databases for this approach to work; it's appropriate in any system that supports some sort of inter-data connectivity. You could do it out of text files, in organised binary, or even through some sort of wacky distributed service on the Cloud if you wanted. The reference to "databases" (like "dictionaries" before it) is just a metaphor.

Comment: Sorry, now you completely lost me. Usage of irregular verb in my example was unintentional. Let's consider "playing" vs "played". Do I understand correctly that you suggest storing only the stemmed form "play" in the main index, but have an additional list of specific suffixes and their occurrences for each main index entry? I can see how that solves  the problem of searching for both stemmed and complete forms, but it does nothing to reduce the database size, as far as I can see. Still, it's a clever  trick. P. S. I, too, only mean some abstract unspecified storage when saying "database".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What's kinda hidden by my answer (which I might rewrite soon, it gets worse every time I look at it) is that the list of suffixes would be reference-able with every item in the mainlist. This reduces total size because most words have similar suffixes. For example, running, eating, and jumping are all progressive terms that end in -ing. Except for "running", they follow the pattern "verb + ing". So everything can be checked against the "ing" suffix, and we can safely store one suffix for three separate cases.

Comment: You can probably see the inefficiency a mile away: every search for terms that aren't necessarily verbs will mean crawling a bajillion verb suffixes. That's why I mentioned verb/adjective/noun categories for each term (maybe tags?), but automating the categorisation process and accounting for neologisms would be tricky, so...idk. If could either be a very effective way to cut back on the time per-word, or it could be complicated and slow everything down. I don't really have enough practice with natural language processing to judge :)

Comment: Aha. This is how I understood your answer initially, but I didn't *really* understand it. If every different word is associated with the same list of suffixes, how or where do I store the occurrences of the specific word with a specific suffix?

Comment: I'm...not sure how you would associate them, to be honest. That's why I was being so vague about it ;). The naive solution is NOT to store it, and to break down your input:

> User inputs "programming"
> Stemming process isolates "program" from "ming"
> Simple inferential analysis concludes that this is an -ing suffix with consonant doubling
> Display links to pages that contain <stem> + <stemLastConsonant> + "ing"
> Display links to pages with <stem> + other verb suffixes
> Display links to pages with reasonably similar (characterwise) suffixes
> Repeat step 2 until you run out...

Comment: ...of characters. Characterwise checking is fast to write but slow to execute, and if you were going to do it by word type you'd probably list suffixes associated with the original type first, then the others in arbitrary order (so if the given suffix is tagged as a verb, you'd list forms with other verb suffixes first in your results, then forms with noun suffixes, and so on). I freely admit that I have no idea how to store this info for actual pages; I'm just telling you how to select the data to run through the search algorithm :)

Also, we should send this to chat :P

Answer (score -1):

You just need four tables

Document
ID    PK
position   PK
wordID

Word
ID    PK
word

stem
ID    PK
stem

StemWord
stemID PK
wordID PK

Search word

select distinct d.ID
from Document d
join Word w
on w.ID = d.wordID
and w.word = 'diminished'

Search stem

select distinct d.ID
from Document d
join StemWord sw
on sw.wordID = d.wordID
join stem s
on s.ID = sw.stemID
and s.stem = stem('diminished')

It is simple. If you find that complex then I suggest you use a free library like Solr.

Comment: A vote to delete without a comment?  Come on what does not work here?  I provide table design and search.

Comment: The votes didn't come from me.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You also asked how to have word and stem.  I showed you how without two separate indexes.  "And worse, for the common search queries that do benefit from stemming, how do I even implement it?"  I showed you how to search on stem and word.   Phrase search should apply equally to stem and word.  You have position - hint it will differ by 1.

Comment: Really that much you understood?  "And worse, for the common search queries that do benefit from stemming, how do I even implement it?  The only solution I see is keeping two indices."  Sure does not indicate to me you understood it.   I was going to edit to add how to do a phrase search.

Comment: Ain't you a fun person to talk to ;)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Ditto - I tied to help you